# Netsuite VendBill Mainline not accessible

Tags: search, netsuite

I have a problem with netsuite search, I want to get taxcode from vendbill but it is inaccessible.
My filters include ['mainline', 'is', 'T'] and searchcolumns include e.g. taxcode, but I cannot get value of this taxcode

Comment: I mean: ['mainline', 'is', 'F']

Answer (score -1):

Tax codes are used by NetSuite to calculate the tax rate to apply to sales transactions like sales orders and invoices - they do not apply to vendor bills.

Furthermore, on sales orders and invoices the tax code is applied per item on the item sublist, so setting a filter of `['mainline', 'is', 'T']` would not show any tax codes anyway.